# Odd behavior involving rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

My gem uses rubyinline for some ruby-evil style stuff (I don't like it but it's the only way to do what I want) and uses rubyinline to do it.

So I've added it to my `.gemspec` with:

`spec.add_runtime_dependency "RubyInline"`

but when I try to test the gem, ruby keeps reporting:

`'require': cannot load such file -- inline (LoadError)`

But when I add to the test's Gemfile:

`gem 'RubyInline'`

It suddenly starts working (well, ok, it errors but for an entirely unrelated reason).

I can see that the correct version of rubyinline is installed as well, so I know it's not that.

whats going on? Why won't it accept that rubyinline is there unless I add it to the gemfile?

Comment: How are you testing your gem? With bundler? Do you have a [`gemspec`](http://bundler.io/v1.7/rubygems.html) line in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: I'm installing and testing the gem in a separate app.

Comment: If you are changing dependencies-of-dependencies, you may need to: 1) Bump version of your gem that you have altered runtime dependency of. 2) Run `bundle update`. There may be other ways to work-around or update, depends what's in the Gemfile of the separate test app. BTW, you should make clearer in the question that your test and error message are in a separate app to the gem.

Comment: I was thinking it was a caching issue, I was right but I was deleting the cache of the gem from the cache folder. I didn't think about bundle's cache, running `bundle update` made the issue go away.